# Flutter code returning The method 'onDisconnect' was called on null when pressing Sign out button

Tags: flutter, dart

The below code doesn't have any error, but can not log out when pressing the logout button. This is the profile tab page code.

> this is the code

```
 class ProfileTabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileTabPageState createState() => _ProfileTabPageState();
}

class _ProfileTabPageState extends State<ProfileTabPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [

              Text(driversInformation.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 65.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

              Text(title + "driver",  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey[200], letterSpacing: 2.5,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

              SizedBox(height: 20.0, width: 200, child: Divider(color: Colors.white,),),

              SizedBox(height: 40.0,),

              InfoCard(
                text: driversInformation.phone,
                icon: Icons.phone,
                onPressed: () async {
                  print("this is phone.");
                },
              ),
              InfoCard(
                text: driversInformation.email,
                icon: Icons.email,
                onPressed: () async {
                print("this is email.");
                },),
              InfoCard(
                text: driversInformation.car_color + " " + driversInformation.car_model + " " + driversInformation.car_number,
                icon: Icons.car_repair,
                onPressed: () async {
                print("this is car info.");},),



              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  makeDriverOfflineNow();

                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, LoginScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);



                },
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 110.0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    trailing: Icon(
                      Icons.follow_the_signs_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,

                    ),

                    title: Text(getTranslated(context,"Sign out"),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),


            ],
          ),
    ),

    );

  }

  void makeDriverOfflineNow(){
    Geofire.removeLocation(currentfirebaseUser.uid);
    rideRequestRef.onDisconnect();
    rideRequestRef.remove();
    rideRequestRef= null;

  }
}

class InfoCard extends StatelessWidget
{

  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  Function onPressed;

  InfoCard({this.text, this.icon, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        margin:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.black87,
          ),
          title: Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: 16.0),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> 

```
this is the error message when pressing the signout button
```

> ======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The method 'onDisconnect' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: onDisconnect()

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _ProfileTabPageState.makeDriverOfflineNow (package:driver_app/tabsPages/profileTabPage.dart:103:20)
#2      _ProfileTabPageState.build. (package:driver_app/tabsPages/profileTabPage.dart:62:19)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:607:11)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#70f77
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: possible
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(187.8, 513.1)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(187.8, 43.6)
button: 1
sent tap down

Comment: What is the rideRequestRef? According to error there is no method called onDisconnect and you are trying to call it with rideRequestRef. Can you share the code about rideRequestRef variable.

Comment: In my main.dart file, I declared Database reference like this for RideRequest Node:          This is somewhere in my main.dart  :     ' DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentfirebaseUser.uid).child("newRide");'